# nodetool cfhistogramsコマンドについて

Tags: cassandra

nodetool cfhistogramsの表示のされ方について、
過去15分間の統計が表示されるとのことですが
この「過去15分間」とは以下のどちらになりますでしょうか。

・コマンドを実行した時の15分前の統計
・コマンドを実行した時の直近15分毎の統計(0:00、0:15、0:30・・・)

Answer (score 0):

Cassandraのバージョンにより異なります。
(Read/Write latency および SSTable per read が対象です。)

- Cassandra v2.1以前: Cassandra起動時、もしくは前回の `cfhistograms` 実行時からの統計 (`cfhistograms` 実行後リセットされる)
- (Cassandra v2.2: おおまかに直近5分 [Exponential decay](https://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/manual/core/#exponentially-decaying-reservoirs))
- Cassandra v3.0以降: 直近5分だがより直前の値を重視 [CASSANDRA-11752](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11752)